# Jquery CDN failed to load in localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, playframework

I am trying to load jQuery from via CDN. The following error occurred while loading page. I am trying on localhost.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js (“default-src”).

Comment: Run your html file using some serve like python SimpleHttpServer.

Comment: is there any work around which make it work on localhost?

Comment: How are you serving the page?

Comment: You have a CSP in place. You need to whitelist the cdn. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp

Comment: I am serving the page using web framework which is Play framework

Comment: This happens when there is a mismatch between your site not having https and the script being hosted on somewhere with https. I'm guessing your localhost doesn't have https. You can just change the js path to a non-https path and it should stop complaining.

Comment: Please try with removing https and start from //ajax.googleapis... Both the protocols should match